# A play with words

Tags: wordplay, language

If my right side is law and my left clumsy,
What is fine, then?

(Please explain your reasoning)

Answer:

> Translating this to French, you get: Si mon cote droit est le droit et ma gauche gauche, Qu'es ce qui est fin?
>  La fin.
>  (the End)
>  I would also have accepted good & almond (though in this case it wasn't an adjective)

Comment: This puzzle is too obvious. The answer is clearly "clumsylaw".

Comment: Wrong. Do explain, though; I'm interested in your reasoning.

Comment: It's just a joke. You told us the left was "clumsy" and the right was "law", so smash them together in that order and you get "clumsylaw". :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:

Some other possible solutions following the most of the same reason as below:

> End, fin is one translation of fine in french and also means end
>  Beauty, beau is one translation of fine in french and also means beauty
>  Subtle/tactful, subtil is one translation of fine in french and also means subltle or tactful
>  There are a bunch of different valid translations just type it into google translate

I think you are:

> Bien

**Reasoning:**

> In french right is droite and droit in french means law. Maladroit means clumsy but can be literally translated to not right (or left) (also guache is french for left and also means clumsy as pointed out by @Gareth McCaughan). Bien is french for fine

Comment: Close, but not correct. You're on the right track, though.

Comment: @Seraviel I think the riddle might be too broad. I'm sure there are at least a few languages that would follow my same reasoning and there is nothing blatantly invalid about my answer

Comment: I believe "gauche" (the French word for "left") also means clumsy.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I don't actually know french, I was mostly basing my answer off of this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_against_left-handed_people) and google translate. The article has a few other languages that fit as well but french seemed to be the most exact fit

Comment: You are right about gauche=clumsy, but you're mistranslating the last part. Also, your answer is in French, not in English.

Answer (score 5):

I honestly think the clue is too vague, but here it goes:

> Amy Schumer

**Reasoning:**

> Who is clumsy? Jar-Jar Binks. In fact, he's the epitome of clumsy, and he even refers to himself as clumsy, using that exact word. If the left side is J, for Jar-Jar, and the right side is "law", you get J-Law. J-Law is a name for Jennifer Lawrence. At the Golden Globes in January, she won and said of Amy Schumer "[She'll be fine.](http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2016/01/jennifer-lawrence-amy-schumer-golden-globes-2016)"

Comment: Nope. And I have no clue how you got to Star Wars from what's above.

Comment: There are actually clumsier characters than Jar Jar. But, no, this riddle doesn't refer to a character.

Comment: Maybe you need to use more specific clues, such that there cannot be so many answers that fit.

Comment: @Gordon is already on the right track, so I don't much see the issue.

Comment: I really like this answer because it fits the riddle and I never in a million years would have come up with it +1